# Pandas isin() - help me get this please

Tags: python, pandas

I just had it working and now it isn't, please someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
dater = data_log[data_log['section'].isin([5, 6])]
```

data_log['section'] in this dataframe contains values of 1-9. For some reason I am only getting values which have a data_log['section'] == 5. Am I doing a stupid syntax error? THank you.

Comment: You syntax is right. You can use `data_log['section'].value_counts()` to check `6`'s count.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

> Whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

So you're checking whether the data frame consists only of 5 and 6, not whether 5 and 6 are in the data frame.